# Hashchange events with the Back Button in the Backbone Router/History

Tags: events, backbone.js, back-button, hashchange

I'm using the following system configuration:

---

Chromium 14.0.835.202 on Ubuntu 11.04 using Backbone 0.5.3

A Backbone Router with the following routes and callbacks defined:

```
, routes: {

                  '': 'handlerRoot'

                , 'second': 'handlerSecond'
}
```

---

In this system I'm having the following behavior:

---

1. If I access the 'root' (the home), the 'handlerRoot' is called.
   OK, it was what I was expecting.
2. If I go to 'second' (#second), the 'handlerSecond' is called. OK,
   it was what I was expecting.
3. If I'm in 'root' and next I go to 'second', and once there I'm
   clicking the Back Button, as a result of pushing the Back Button two
   callbacks are being called: first is called 'handlerSecond', and
   next 'handlerRoot'.  Here in fact I was expecting that only
   'handlerRoot' is called, cause my intention as a user when I pushed
   the Back Button was to return to the previous page.
4. If I'm doing the following path: 'root' -> 'second' -> 'root' ->
   'second', and once in 'second' (the last one), I'm clicking the Back
   Button, as a result of this pushing are called the following
   callbacks:  First 'handlerSecond', next  'handlerRoot', next
   'handlerSecond', and finally  'handlerRoot'. Its like all the callbacks associated to the URL paths in the previous history are called (in reverse order). Again, my expectaction was only being called 'handlerRoot' (for the same reason, I'm coming back from 'second' to root, I'm not interested in all the history).

---

I was watching the Backbone.js code for History and I saw that is using the 'onhashchange' event (for the compatible browsers). So, I set manually in the browser console the following:

---

```
function locationHashChanged() {
                  console.log(window.location.toString()) 
};
window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

---

I did the same experiments (1), (2), (3) and (4) with this configuration. Effectively all the URL paths in the previous history were printed in reverse order. For example in (3), when I'm pushing the Back Button, first is printed the URL for 'second', and next is printed the URL for 'root'. So, the Backbone behavior indeed is the 'onhashchange' behavior.

My question is:

Which one is the reason of this behavior (for what is it useful)? Cause for example if my callbacks are only switching views, in the example (4), I'm switching views four times, when I'm really needing to switch the views only one time (change the view being presented in 'second' by the view being presented in 'root').   Is there some way to get this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Andreas, now the text looks more clear :)

Comment: Using backbone 0.5.3 with Chrome, the following code works as expected: `code` var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({        , routes: {

                  '': 'handlerRoot'

                , 'second': 'handlerSecond'
}, handlerRoot: function( actions ){ alert('handlerRoot');}, second : function( actions ){ alert('second') } });      `code`  I think that something else is going on with your code...  Maybe your problem is in something you do in the views, and not in the router?

Comment: I agree with @Robert.  As I was first reading this it was beginning to sound like zombie views.  Can you post some more code, perhaps of what you're doing in handlerRoot and handlerSecond?

Comment: @Robert, indeed its a problem with Chromium as Atinux is noting. I was testing in Firefox 8.0 on Ubuntu 11.04, and it works as expected (only calling one callback).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : 
After multiples search, Chromium has just a bug on the console with the back button, the route is trigger just one time like the others browsers.

---

I created a jsFiddle to try your problem and I don't see the problem.

- You can test the routes here : http://jsfiddle.net/Atinux/V36ZU/show/
- And see the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/Atinux/V36ZU/

I tested this with Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Linux 10.04 and there is nothing wrong...but Chromium (15.0.874.106) has the bug with the back button. So I think that Chromium doesn't interpreted correctly the history object from Backbone JS.

I answered to an issue on the GitHub repository to re-open it here : https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/646#issuecomment-3291944

Comment: So, the problem isn't only with Chromium 15.0.874.106 that you was testing , but also with the 14.0.835.202 version (my version).

Comment: Ok I understood, Chromium has just a bug on the console.log with the back button, but your route is executed just one time, like the other web browsers. Look my jsFiddle, I actualized it. As you can see, each route trigger will create and <div> and add on the list, test the jsfiddle on Chromium and you will see that even if the bug on console is present, there are no problem on the example.